# pid_t doesnt highlight by default in VIM

Tags: linux, vim

All datatypes like int,long,char are highlighted automatically as soon as i type them in VIM.
But, there are few exceptions like pid_t,mode_t..

How do get them highlighted by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add them to `syntax/c.vim` in your [after directory](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#after-directory), so they complement the distributed `syntax/c.vim`.  For example:

```
syn keyword cType pid_t mode_t
```

See also the ["Adding to an Existing Syntax File"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_44.html#44.11) section of the user manual.

Answer (score 1):

There's a directory `/usr/share/vim/vim72/` where you can edit files like `c.vim` and add the keywords manually.

Comment: Editing the distributed files is a bad idea as they'll be overwritten every time you upgrade.  There's a reason a user-specific directory is included in the `runtimepath` option.

Comment: i had to append this line by pid_t...                               :- syn keyword     cType           int long short char void pid_t

Comment: @jamessan
so how do i actually do that.